If $g:A\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ is an injective function then $A$ is a countable set.
What I have so far: Since $g$ maps $A$ onto the image set of $A$ under $g$, $g$ is a one-to-one function from $A$ onto $g(A)$. Thus, $A$ is equinumerous with $g(A)$, which we denote by $A \sim g(A)$. Let $B = g(A)$. Then $A\sim B$ and $B\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. If we can show that $B$ is countable, then $A$ must be countable as well, so that is what we will prove. If $B$ is finite, then by definition $B$ is countable, so assume that $B$ is infinite. We must prove that $B$ is denumerable, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}^{+}\sim B$, i.e. that there exists a bijective function $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ to $B$. We can define $f$ recursively by the following:
$$f(n)=\text{the smallest element of }B-\{f(m): m\in\mathbb{Z}^{+},m\lt n\},\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}.$$
To use the well-ordering principle and ensure that a smallest element exists for the set specified above, we need to prove that this set is nonempty for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Suppose, to the contrary that $B-\{f(m): m\in\mathbb{Z}^{+},m\lt n\}=\emptyset$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Then $B\subseteq \{f(m): m\in\mathbb{Z}^{+},m\lt n\}$. Since every subset of a finite set is also finite, I could produce a contradiction if I can show that $\{f(m): m\in\mathbb{Z}^{+},m\lt n\}$ is a finite set. How do I show that $\{f(m): m\in\mathbb{Z}^{+},m\lt n\}$ is finite?

This one is very tricky.

Please include the question in the post, not just the title. The title is like an index entry, not the beginning of the post.

What is your definition of "finite"? Because there is a very obvious surjection from ${1,\ldots,n-1} = n$ onto ${f(m)\mid 0\lt m\lt n}$.

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $I_n = {i\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}: i\leq n}$. Then a set A is finite if there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $I_{n}\sim A$.

@ArturoMagidin I was thinking I could define a function $f^{}:I_{n-1}\rightarrow {f(m):m\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}, m\lt n}$ by the rule $f^{}(i)=f(i)$ for all $i\in I_{n-1}$. This would be a surjective function, but this feels a bit circular since I haven't established that $f(i)$ is defined.

$f(1)$ is defined. If you assume that $f|{n-1}$ is defined and the image is finite, then $f|{n}$ gets defined and has a finite image. I don't see the issue.

What does that notation with the bar mean?

It means "restriction to". If $f$ is already defined on $n-1={0,1,\ldots,n-2}$ with finite image, then we can define $f$ on $n={0,1,\ldots,n-2,n-1}$ with finite image.
